# Oscillations mechanics problem

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

Hello i was wondering if anyone can help me with the following two parts of this problem, i cannot seem to find my notes on questions like this and im struggling, any help would be brilliant, thanks ( see the attatched picture )

for part a of the problem i'm sure it just involves resolving but then it confuses me when it is asking for the initial conditions.
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far ? What are your thoughts on the problem? Do you know Newotn's $2^{nd}$ law of motion?

Comment: newtons second law of motion is just F=ma if i'm correct? when t =0 and x=0 the force F=0 since it is stationary i enjoy pure mathematics a little bit more then the applied stuff as its harder for me to see an approach, but i've been trying to draw a diagram but i dont think it is correct.

Comment: @KonKan is it possible for you to give me some more assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's second law says $F=ma$. Your force is given by the spring $F=k\Delta x$. The extent of the spring is $\Delta x=vt-x$. Therefore $$ma=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=kvt-kx$$ or $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{k}{m}x=\frac{kv}{m}t$$ The initial conditions are $x(0)=0$, $\frac{dx}{dt}(0)=0$, and $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}(0)=0$. With $\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$, the solution has the form $x(t)=A\cos{\omega t}+B\sin{\omega t}+C+Dt$. The last term comes from the right side of the equation of motion

Comment: can we use the method of undetermined coefficients  when determining the particular integral?, thank you for this solution it is laid out very clearly. merry christmas.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I just wanted to say that you should get the same result if you work in the reference frame of the locomotive. You will not have the $kvt$ term in the equation of motion, but your initial condition will be $\frac{dx}{dt}=-v$. When going back to the track frame, you will need to add $vt$ to the coordinate

Comment: hi thanks for your response is it possible you could tell me what a suitable trial function is that i could choose to find the particular solution, i tried at+c as the rhs is of linear form but i'm struggling

Comment: It is a first order polynomial. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: when substituting it in to the lhs of the equation, for example the value of c that i calculated in you're equation turns out to be 0 is this correct?, if i set the first order polynomial to be C+DT then when differentiating y'=Dt,y''=t, then substituting into the ode you get t+(k/m)(c+dt)=(kv/m)(T) so here d=0, c=vt?

Comment: For $y=C+Dt$ $y'=D$ and $y''=0$. The second derivative is 0, so $k/m (C+Dt)=kvt/m$. This means $C=0$ and $D=kv$

Comment: Thank you for this it was causing me problems because i'm only used to solving these type of differential equations in a pure manor  ie ones that just include x and y for example

Comment: hey when factorising the particular integral shouldnt it be negative and positive omega? i dont understand

Comment: For the cosine solution $\cos(-\omega t)=\cos(\omega t)$, so it does not matter. For sine $\sin(-\omega t)=-\sin(\omega t)$, so it gets absorbed into the coefficient that you calculate from the initial conditions

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification, so when using the initial conditions to find a and b would we substitute the conditions into the general solution or the equation of motion?

Comment: the general solution